# Multi device auto-testing tool for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, ipad, automated-tests

I want to run my UI tests on multiple iOS devices both, virtual and real. I want a full range of Apple iOS devices, iPhones-iPads to be included into my test. For Android platform there is a Firebase product with its Test Lab project for Android. However for iOS platform I hasn't found a free platform which will enable this kind of testing.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the URL for all types of mobile & web device for limited use for free

URL:- [perfectomobile.com](http://perfectomobile.com)